# How to check if element being dragged has a certain class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, draggable

How can I check if a certain element being dragged has a certain class?

The JS code:

```
if ($('.fc-event').is('.ui-draggable')) //To check if element is being dragged
{
    console.log('This element is being dragged');
    if ($('.fc-event').is('.ui-draggable').hasClass('music')) //Can't use this.hasClass?
    {
        //place in music database table
    }
    else
    {
        //place in other database table
    }
}
```

The HTML code:

```
<div id='external-events'>
    <h4>Music</h4>
    <div class='fc-event music'>Music 1</div>
    <div class='fc-event music'>Music 2</div>
    <div class='fc-event music'>Music 3</div>
</div>
```

The above JS code obviously does not work, but it's the closest to the solution. (I think)

Comment: you can get it from callbacks, there are args like `event, ui` where `ui` will be the dragged element.

Comment: You can't use `hasClass` there because `is()` returns a boolean and booleans have no `hasClass` method.

Comment: Why are you checking if its draggable twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some events in `draggable()` api, there is one said `drag` which fires when you drag it and this callback has two arguments `event, ui` where `ui` will get you the element you are looking for.

```js
$( ".selector" ).draggable({
  drag: function( event, ui ) {
    $('pre').html('$(ui.helper).hasClass("music"):'+$(ui.helper).hasClass('music'));
  }
});
```

```css
.selector{width:150px; height:100px; border:solid 1px red; background:yellow;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class='selector music'>selector</div>

<pre></pre>
```